# How to iterate over a list<T> and alter it at the same time?

Tags: c#, list

I have a List that i want to delete some members from. I want to use this kind of syntax :

```
List<Object> Foo = new List<Object>();

//Some code

foreach (Object obj in Foo)
    if (obj.ShouldBeDeleted())
        Foo.Remove(obj);
```

It felt wrong to iterate over a list and modify it at the same time, and a quick test confirmed it with an InvalidOperationException.

What is the correct way to selectively remove members of a list? I thought of using a copy of the list, and iterate over the copy while I delete from the original list, but it does not feel very memory efficient.

Comment: foreach Foo.ToList() to have a copy of the list.

Comment: @OlivierRogier That's the worst possible answer - keeping a list of items to remove isn't ideal, but it's cheaper than copying the entire source list. There are better answers in the suggested duplicate, like `RemoveAll` and iterating over the list backwards.

Comment: You can either iterate by index in reverse, or make a new list `Foo.Where(f=>!f.ShouldBeDeleted()).ToList()`

Comment: There already is a list member to do exactly what you want: [`List.RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8), which removes from the list all its elements that satisfy a predicate.

Comment: Did not see that it removes all, indeed @MatthewWatson.